# Similar syntax of "SET IDENTITY OFF" in Ms Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to copy records from one database to other database in MS-Access database.

I have some table whose ID is stored as foreign key in other table.

Now i want something Similar syntax to "SET IDENTITY OFF" of sql in Ms Access

can any body help me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything like `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ... ON/OFF` to insert rows into an ACE/Jet (Access) database table that has an AutoNumber (identity) column. Just INSERT the rows and the database engine will accept values for the AutoNumber field provided that they are of the correct type and do not cause any duplicate key conflicts.

For a table like this:
ID - AutoNumber, Primary Key
Item - Text(255)

The following Excel VBA code works just fine

```
Sub IdentityInsertTest()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\Database1.accdb;"
con.Execute "INSERT INTO tblSampleData (ID, Item) VALUES (1001, 'item1001')"
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```